# json.dump() uses ASCII codec encoding (instead of requested UTF-8) when redirecting stdout to a file

Tags: python, json, unicode, utf-8

This tiny python program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import json
import sys

x = { "name":u"This doesn't work β" }

json.dump(x, sys.stdout, ensure_ascii=False, encoding="utf8")
print
```

Generates this output when run at a terminal:

```
$ ./tester.py
{"name": "This doesn't work β"}
```

Which is exactly as I would expect. However, if I redirect stdout to a file, it fails:

```
$ ./tester.py > output.json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tester.py", line 9, in <module>
json.dump(x, sys.stdout, ensure_ascii=False, encoding="utf8")
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 190, in dump
fp.write(chunk)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u03b2' in position 19: ordinal not in range(128)
```

However, a direct print (without json.dump) can can be redirect to file:

```
 print u"This does work β".encode('utf-8')
```

It's as if the json package ignores the **encoding** option if stdout is not a terminal.

How can I get the json package to do what I want?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208530/discussion-on-question-by-edward-falk-json-dump-uses-ascii-codec-encoding-ins).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consolidating all the comments and answers into one final answer:

**Note:** this answer is for Python 2.7. Python 3 is likely to be different.

The json spec says that json files are utf-8 encoded. However, the Python json package does not like to take chances and so writes straight ascii and escapes unicode characters in the output.

You can set the **ensure_ascii** flag to False, in which case the json package will generate unicode output instead of str. In that case, encoding the unicode output is your problem.

There is no way to make the json package generate utf-8 or any other encoding on output. It's either ascii or unicode; take your pick.

The **encoding** argument was a red herring. That option tells the json package how the *input* strings are encoded.

Here's what finally worked for me:

```
ofile = codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(sys.stdout)
json.dump(x, ofile, ensure_ascii=False)
```

tl;dr: the real mystery was why didn't it barf when just letting stdout go to the terminal. It turned out that stdout.write() was detecting when output was to a terminal and encoding per the $LANG environment variable. When output goes to a file, the unicode is encoded to ascii, and an error results when a non-encodable character is encountered.

Answer (score 3):

**JSON is a text serialization format (that incidentally has a recommended binary encoding), not a binary serialization format.** The `json` module itself only cares about encoding to the extent that it would like to know what Python 2's terrible `str` type is supposed to represent (is it ASCII bytes? UTF-8 bytes? latin-1 bytes?).

Since Python 2 text handling is, as stated, terrible, the `json` module is happy to return either `str` (when `ensure_ascii` is true, or the stars align in other cases and it's convinced you've told it `str` is compatible with your expected `encoding`, and none of the inputs are actually `unicode`) or `unicode` (when `ensure_ascii` is false, most of the time).

Like the rest of Python 2, `sys.stdout` is a bit wishy-washy. Even if it is set to an `encoding='ascii'` by your locale settings, it ignores it when you write a `str` to it (`sys.stdout.write('\xe9')` should fail, but instead, it treats the `str` as pre-encoded raw binary data and doesn't bother to verify it matches the expected encoding. But **when `unicode` comes in, it doesn't have that option; `unicode` is *text* (not UTF-8 text, not ASCII text, etc.), from the ideal text world of unicorns and rainbows, and that world isn't expressed in tawdry bytes.**

**So `sys.stdout` *must* encode the result, and it does so with the locale determined encoding (`sys.stdout.encoding` will tell you what it is). When that's ASCII, and it receives something that can't encode to ASCII, it explodes (as it should).**

The point is, the `json` module is always returning *text* (either `unicode`, or `str` that it's convinced is effectively text in the wishy-washy Python 2 world), and *sometimes* you get lucky and that text happens to be in a format that bypasses checks in `sys.stdout`.

But you shouldn't be relying on that. If your output must be in a specific encoding, *use that encoding*. The simplest way to do this (simplest in the sense that it pushes most work to the interpreter to do for you) is to not use `sys.stdout` (explicitly, or implicitly via `print`) and write your data to files *you* open [with `io.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) (a backport of Python 3's `open`, that properly handles encodings), explicitly specifying `encoding='utf-8'`. If you *must* use `sys.stdout`, and you insist on ignoring the locale encoding, you can rewrap it, e.g.:

```
with io.open(sys.stdout.fileno(), encoding='utf-8', closefd=False) as encodedout:
    json.dump(x, encodedout, ensure_ascii=False, encoding="utf-8")
```

which temporarily wraps the `stdout` file descriptor in a modern file-like object (using `closefd` to avoid closing the underlying descriptor when it's closed).

**TL;DR: Switch to Python 3.** Python 2 is *awful* when it comes to non-ASCII text, and its modules are often even worse (`json` should absolutely be returning a consistent type, or at least just one type for each setting of `ensure_ascii`, not dynamically selecting based on the inputs and `encoding`; it's not even the worst either, the `csv` module is absolutely awful). Also, it's reached end-of-life, and will not be patched for *anything* from here on out, so continuing to use it leaves you vulnerable to any security problems found between the beginning of this year and the end of time. Among other things, Python 3 uses `str` exclusively for text (which has the full Unicode support of Py2's `unicode` type) and modern Python 3 (3.7+) will [coerce ASCII locales to UTF-8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#pep-538-legacy-c-locale-coercion) (because basically all systems can actually handle the latter), which should fix all your problems. Non-ASCII text will behave the same as ASCII text, and weirdo locales like yours that insist they're ASCII (and therefore won't handle non-ASCII output) will be "fixed" to work as you desire, without manually encoding and decoding, rewrapping file handles, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is an environment variable Python uses that can override encoding to the terminal or for redirection, so this should work without wrapping stdout inside the script.

```
$ export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8
$ ./tester.py > output.json
```

Comment: Mind you, simply tweaking the locale variables (`LANG` at the simplest) would achieve the same effect (and others, which would probably be better for the system as a whole, rather than only having Python use a different encoding). While the comment thread on the question was moved to chat, part of it explained that the choice of Python 2.7 was so that it would run on any Mac without relying on the user changing their environment in any way. So environment/locale tweaks only work if they're incorporated into the script itself.

Comment: @ShadowRanger use the shell for redirection, use a shell variable to control the redirection.

Comment: That's good to know. However, I don't want to tell users to set an environment variable just to run my software.